# Узнать запущен ли процесс по PID

Tags: php, windows, процесс

Есть консольный скрипт (1), который при запуске пишет в базу свой PID полученный функцией getmypid()

И другой скрипт (2), который проверяет запущен ли процесс с заданным PID,
для этого он использует команду вида:

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 12348" | find "php.exe"
```

Исполняется команда через shell_exec

где 12348 - PID нужного процесса

Так вот в чём вопрос, если выполнить эту команду в консоли руками, то всё работает, процесс находится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А сам скрипт выводит пустую строку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public static function isProcessRunning($pid)
    {
        $windowsCommand = 'tasklist /FI "PID eq ' . $pid . '" | find "php.exe"';
        $linuxCommand = "ps --pid " . $pid . " | grep php | grep " . $pid;

        $command = $windowsCommand;

        if (static::isLinuxOS()) {
            $command = $linuxCommand;
        }

        $output = shell_exec($command);

        var_dump($command);
        var_dump($output);

        return !empty(trim($output));
    }
```

В чём может быть проблема?

PS:

Если писать так, или вообще без аргументов

```
<?php
        var_dump(trim(shell_exec('tasklist /FI "PID eq 492"')));
    ?>
```

то всё работает так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `tasklist` в принципе-то при запуске без параметров то выводит результат? и есть ли что-нибудь в `error.log`?

Comment: обновил описание проблемы. error.log ничего по теме нету

Comment: вы уверены что `getmypid` возвращает то что надо? у меня на локале (апач) команда `tasklist /FI "PID eq 2180" | find "cmd"` выполняется нормально. зы: не понял зачем после поиска по `PID` еще `find` делать.

Comment: дело в том, что скрипт выполняется долго, может доходить и до 20 часов, поэтому надо убедиться что это именно php процесс. В подлинности PID сомнений нет, потому что его можно отследить из консоли и из диспетчера задач.

Comment: я про то, что если сделать `print $command` и запихать это в cmd, то там будет ожидаемый результат?

Comment: да, совершенно верно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54067/discussion-between-s4urp8n-and-teran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Особенности запуска таких функций как shell_exec, exec, system в том что они пытаются сбросить буфер вывода, что при запуске из браузера приводит к потере данных. Поэтому их в данном случае использовать нельзя.

Это ошибка №1.

Запускаем процессы так:

```
$handle = popen($command, 'r');
$output = stream_get_contents($handle);
pclose($handle);

return $output;
```

Ошибка №2 заключалась в том что дополнительные команды Windows типа find или же просто tasklist могут выдавать надписи на русском языке (потому что система у меня русская) и использование trim выдавало неожиданные результаты. Необходимо использовать другие функции обработки строк и поиска совпадений.

Итоговая, правильная функции лежит тут: https://github.com/s4urp8n/common